# openshift nodejs app cors 502 No Access-Control-Allow-Origin specified

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am building some prototype api's using the openshift default node.js app but for some reason I am getting a No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header specified error with the following code, can someone explain what I am doing wrong:

```
self.createRoutes = function() {

        self.routes = { };

        self.routes['/api/getusers/:username'] = function(req, res) {

            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

            client.users.search({query: req.params.username}, function (err, req, result) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({'err':JSON.parse(err)});
                return;
              }
              res.json({'success': result});
            });

        };

...
```

I have used similar headers on other projects and it works fine, I am guessing some sort of scope issue here but can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I moved the headers to a middleware function instead of at the route level, works fine now.

```
self.app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
      next();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! I put your code in my  self.initializeServer = function()  and it works perfectly.